# Rigorous definition of the energy-momentum operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

Given a Hilbert space $H$, let $\Gamma(H)$ denote the associated Fock space. Let $a^*$ be the standard creation operator-valued distribution on the Fock space $\Gamma(L^2(\mathbb{R}^3))$, i.e.
$$
a^*(\xi) \psi = \sqrt{n+1} ~S(\xi \otimes \psi), ~~ \psi \textrm{ is an $n$-particle state}
$$
where $S$ is the symmetrization operator.

Then the integral notation commonly used by the physicists is *defined* by the following formula:
$$
\int \xi(p) a^*(p) dp := a^*(\xi), ~ \xi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)
$$
and similarly
$$
\int \xi(p) a(p) dp := a(\xi), ~ \xi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3), ~~~~(*)
$$

However, later on in QFT one uses integrals containing both $a^*(p)$ and $a(p)$ in a single formula. For instance, in the definition of the energy-momentum operator, one uses
$$
P^i = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3 2p^0} p^i a^*(p) a(p)
$$
where $p_0 = \sqrt{p^2 + m^2}$.

This formula doesn't make any sense to me, for we have not defined the meaning of expressions of such form. In other words, $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3 2p^0} p^i a^*(p)$ is not a function and we can't use the formula $(*)$.

How to make sense of the above expression in a rigorous way? (disclaimer: I'm coming from a mathematics background)

Comment: $P^i$ is an unbounded operator, so I'd guess that the idea is that when $\psi$ is in its domain, $(p^i/p^0)a(p)\psi$ is a (Fock-space-valued) test function for $a^*(p)$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270598/rigorous-definition-of-the-commutator-ak-1-a-astk-2-of-creation-and-an